# Using SAML as a bridge for an Unencrypted HTTP header protected site

Tags: java, servlets, proxy, translation, saml

I'm trying to read up on SAML 2.0 as much as I can and would like to know if it is possible to, perhaps, put a SAML proxy (not sure of the right terminology but architecturally this makes sense to me) that would trap inbound SAML requests and perform a "translation" to an [Unencrypted HTTP Header protected website](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Unencrypted_HTTP_Header_%28SiteMinder%29).

To the the client, it "looks" like a SAML protected site but in reality, there's a Java Servlet (or something Java-esque) that does all the processing but in actually is sending (or proxying) only what is needed to the Unencrytped HTTP Header-only SSO website.

Is this possible?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more it looks like I'm trying to build a SAML-proxy, if you will.

Comment: I fixed your link formatting. I'll post an answer when I get to a workstation that allows me to search for the word "proxy" (dammit, lightspeed systems)

Comment: Thanks!  I do hope I made it somewhat clear as to what my intentions are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the Shibboleth SP does exactly what you have described.

Shibboleth SP can be installed as a module on Apache, IIS, etc. It works as a gate to your real webapp. It handles the authentication, and pass out the user information through environment variables or http heads to your webapp.

You may want to read through pages here https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/Home to fully understand how it works. I am pretty sure it works very like what you want.

Comment: I haven't looked at the link you provided but this Shibboleth will allow me to "wrap" or "proxy" my application, which uses a VERY SIMPLE SSO mechanism and allow SAML clients to use it?

Comment: If you use Shibboleth SP, your application doesn't even need to be aware of any SSO mechanism. Code change in your app is very limited. The Shibboleth SP handles everything for you, and set some environment variables for you. You app just need to get these variables. That's it.

Comment: I haven't been able to vet the entire process but it looks like its completely achievable.  I'm just trying, now, to tie my proprietary application as a protected site but it looks promising.